# Heroku Webapp CRASHING when process type is configured in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am creating web service and using embedded tomcat in my application. For this, I've implemented a main class(Main.java) where Tomcat server instance is created.

Now for deploying this application on heroku, I am using maven plugin. In configuration tag I've given process type as:

```
<processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
</processTypes>
```

when deployed, app is crashed saying  Main class not found, also I've kept Main.java in root directory.Do I need to make some changes in command?

Above is my eclipse directory structure.
[image: eclpse directory structure]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Main.java` is not in your Maven `src` directory. I doubt it's even being compiled by Maven (but Eclipse probably does compile it).

Try moving the `Main.java` file into the `src/main/java` directory.